# Proof verification : $n\cdot \int_{0}^{1} x^n \cdot f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}f(1) $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification, definite-integrals, proof-writing

Let $f: [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. Proove that : 
$$n\cdot \displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} x^n \cdot f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}f(1) $$

I would like to know if what I've done is correct, because my book's solution isn't the same at all and seems more complicated.

Using Riemann sum we know that :

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{0}^{1} x^n \cdot f(x) \mathrm{d}x = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\cdot\sum_{i = 0}^{n} g(\frac{i}{n})$ where $g(x) = x^n \cdot f(x)$.
Hence : $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n\cdot\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \cdot x^n \mathrm{d}x = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i = 0}^{n}g(\frac{i}{n})$
Yet note that for all $x \in [0, 1[$ $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x^n\cdot f(x) = 0$ and for $x = 1$ we have $g(1) = f(1)$.

Thus : $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n\cdot\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \cdot x^n \mathrm{d}x = f(1)$

Comment: "Using Riemann sum we know that :" *Why* do we know that, exactly? Riemann sums allow us to say that for every **fixed** $n_0$, $$\int_0^1 x^{n_0} f(x)dx = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n g\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)$$ with $g(x) = x^{n_0}f(x)$. This is not quite what you wrote... Note the absence of limits on the left hand side.

Comment: I don't know how to describe it in proper English but the $n$ you are taking to infinity is not the same $n$ you have to take to infinity when computing the integral through the Riemann sum. Actually you have two limits that need to be taken  and you just ignore one of them. Is this a little bit clear?

Comment: Ok understood, so saying that : $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 0}^{n} g(\frac{i}{n}) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i = 0}^{n} \lim_{n' \rightarrow \infty} (\frac{i}{n})^{n'}\cdot f(\frac{i}{n})^{n'}$ is wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Using Riemann sum we know that :" *Why* do we know that, exactly? Riemann sums allow us to say that for every **fixed** $n_0$, $$\int_0^1 x^{n_0} f(x)dx = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n g\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)$$ with $g(x) = x^{n_0}f(x)$. This is not quite what you wrote... Note the absence of limits on the left hand side.

In particular, you are confusing the $n$ (which I wrote $n_0$ to avoid this ambiguity) on the left and the $n$ which goes to infinity in the Riemann sum. Correcting this, what you want to consider is actually
$$
\lim_{n_0\to\infty}\int_0^1 x^{n_0} f(x)dx = \lim_{n_0\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n g_{n_0}\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)
$$
(writing explicitly the dependence of $g$ on $n_0$). And now, essentially what you want to do in your approach is to swap the two limits in the RHS, writing $$\lim_{n_0\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{n_0\to\infty}$$
But you *cannot* do that in general. You need assumptions for this swap to be correct, and that's the crux of the proof.

Comment: Ok, understood thank you !

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

The application of Riemann sums as given in the OP is flawed.   So, I thought it would be instructive to present a hint on a way forward.

To that end, enforce the substitution $x\mapsto x^{1/n}$ to arrive at

$$\begin{align}
n\int_0^1 x^n f(x)\,dx&=\int_0^1 f(x^{1/n})x^{1/n}\,dx
\end{align}$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking about -- they want to know why *their* proof is wrong, not how to do it in a different way.

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, I do see that.  But inasmuch as the OP's way forward is a dead end, I thought it might be instructive to provide a useful hint.

Comment: Not disputing that :) And after your edit, this is clear from your answer.

Comment: Nice hint :) If I am not mistaken $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} x^{1/n} \cdot f(x^{1/n}) \mathrm{d}x =\int_{0}^{1} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  x^{1/n} \cdot f(x^{1/n}) \mathrm{d}x$ Hence because $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} = x^{1/n}\cdot f(x^{1/n}) = f(1)$ we have the desired result.

Comment: @Salutsalut1 Indeed, you have it!

Comment: @Salutsalut1 You interchanging the limits here is correct, however it is not always the case that $\lim \int = \int \lim$. To say that you want to invoke either dominated convergence from measure theory, or bounded convergence from real analysis theory

Comment: @clark Thank you for this explanation, can you provide an example that shows this is not true ?

Comment: @Salutsalut1 An example can be found in the wikipedia page discussion of the assumptions of the dominated convergence theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for Riemann sums. Let us assume that $f$ is a $C^1$ function on $[0,1]$.

$$ \int_{0}^{1}(n+1)x^n f(x)\,dx = \left[x^{n+1} f(x)\right]_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}x^{n+1} f'(x)\,dx = \color{red}{f(1)}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
since $|f'(x)|\leq M$ for any $x\in[0,1]$. It follows that
$$ n\int_{0}^{1} x^n\,f(x)\,dx = \frac{n}{n+1}\,f(1) + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right). $$
On the other hand $C^1([0,1])$ is dense in $C^0([0,1])$ with the respect to the uniform norm, hence
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} n\int_{0}^{1} x^n f(x)\,dx = f(1) $$
holds for any $f\in C^0([0,1])$.

Comment: NIcely done, thank you !

Comment: Why are you integrating up twice?

Comment: @TheOscillator: before I applied integration by parts in the wrong way. Now fixed.

Comment: Why the fact that : $C^{1}([0, 1])$ is dense in $C^{0}([0, 1])$ means that this limit is true in $C^{0}([0, 1])$ ?

Comment: @Salutsalut1: because $n\int_{0}^{1}x^n\varepsilon \,dx$ is bounded by $\varepsilon$, hence by replacing $f(x)$ with $\tilde{f}(x)\in C^1$ the limit is unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

Some additional problems with the solution posted.

In $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n\cdot\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \cdot x^n \mathrm{d}x = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i = 0}^{n}g(\frac{i}{n})$ you say that each $g(\frac{i}{n})$ go to zero expect $g(1)$. However, the number of terms that go to zero is infinite which gives the indeterminate form $0\cdot \infty$.

Your approach, could have be written in the following way, there is a sequence $k_n>>n$ such that 
$\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}n\int_{0}^{1} x^n \cdot f(x) \mathrm{d}x = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{n}{k_n}\cdot\sum_{i = 0}^{k_n} g(\frac{i}{k_n})$, to make it work you need to find a $\tilde{k}_n<k_n$ such that

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{n}{k_n}\cdot\sum_{i = 0}^{\tilde{k}_n}g(\frac{i}{k_n})=0 \text{ and } \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{n}{k_n}\cdot\sum_{i=\tilde{k}_n}^{k_n} g(\frac{i}{k_n})=f(1)$$